# How to add text to bootstrap mobile menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, text, menu, navbar

I'd like to add some text to the bootstrap menu that appears on mobile devices. Currently the 3 icon bars display as a button on the right side of the menu when the browser window width falls below the media query threshold. There's all that empty space on the left side of the menu bar that I'd like to add some text. Whatever I've tried so far either displays the text on the normal menu, or displays it inside a button frame. Can anyone suggest the best way to accomplish this?

ex.

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
<span class="navbar-toggle small text-left">Text Here</span>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="../about.html">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="../glass-services.html">Services</a></li>
              <li><a href="../contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post the html/css from what you have tried so far.

Comment: Ok, I see you helped me format the code. Was having a hard time. Thx.

Comment: You seem to be pretty close, the text is showing where you want it to, if you want to adjust the styling/remove the border just edit the CSS on the element that contains "Text Here"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the [bootstrap responsive utility classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes).

Therefore do this:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
   <p class="navbar-text visible-xs-inline-block">Text Here</p>
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
       <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
 </div>
```

[**Working Example**](http://www.bootply.com/m4xeqxp5nQ)