# How can I change the 3x icon-bar in Bootstrap collapsible Navbar to my own hamburger icon?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, glyphicons

This is the example for a Bootstrap 3 collapsible navbar.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <p class="navbar-text visible-xs-inline-block">Text Here</p>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to change:

```
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
```

to my own hamburger-icon like this:

```
<span class="hamburger-menu"></span>
```

I want the hamburger-menu icon to look **exactly** like the other glyphicons bootstrap 3 normally uses (I beleave they use the halfling set and that they are 14x14 pixels, but I might be wrong about this...).

I also want to add an envelope glyphicon + a badge (telling the user how many unread messages he/she has) in the right part of the navbar, same as the hamburger-menu but to the left of the hamburger-menu icon and get it all to line up vertically.

I've tried the solution here: [How to add text to bootstrap mobile menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25872529/how-to-add-text-to-bootstrap-mobile-menu) but the text is added in the left part of the navbar, next to the brand. Also if I add glypicon and badge to it they look odd (not vertically aligned).

I have also not been able to figure out how to change the 3x icon-bars to my own hamburger. I have made my own icon (14x14pixels) and store it locally. I also have a custom.css that will add/overvrite the Bootstrap css. However I can't figure out what classes to manipulate and how.

Someone please help?

Comment: Can't you write `CSS` for it if you just want to change `color`?

Comment: 3x Icon-bars is bigger than the other glyphicons, I want the hamburger menu to look like them...

Comment: do you have any `image` or  `code` of which you're referring ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the spans:

```
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
```

and add your icon directly to the button class like so,

```
 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle hamburger-menu" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
 </button>
```